# How to create a product in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I create my first module in Prestashop 1.7.4. This is my code:

```
public function createProductsObject()
    {
        $product = new Product;
        $product->name = $productName;
        $product->ean13 = '';
        $product->reference = '';
        $product->id_category_default = $getCategoryID;
        $product->category = $getCategoryID;
        $product->indexed = 1;
        $product->description = $description;
        $product->condition = 'new';
        $product->redirect_type = '404';
        $product->visibility = 'both';
        $product->id_supplier = 1;
        $product->link_rewrite = $link_rewrite;
        $product->quantity = $singleStock;
        $product->price = $price;
        $product->active = 1;
        $product->psoft_hurtobergamo_id = $productID;
        $product->add();

        $product->addToCategories($getCategoryID);
```

This function in not complite. But this is not important right now. Variable productName hase this value:

```
Array ( [0] => Test [1] => Test) )
```

Beacause I have two language. The problem is. Why I dont have the name after the product is create ?

thanks for help.

Comment: productName should be an array as you did, but the index should be the id_lang. Your languages id don't start at 0. Could be 1 and 2 (not sure if you deleted or deactivated another language before).

Comment: Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem I add new index to my array.

```
$productName = array('0' => '');
$link_rewrite = array('0' => '');
```

and then add values to array start from index 1. Because the first language has identity value set to 1. The second, 2.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $getNumberOfAvailableLanguage; $i++)
       {
 array_push($productName, $name);
array_push($link_rewrite, $clean1);
                }
```